# Can't install back a purged package in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, aptitude, packages, purge

Hello all i've just migrated my desktop machine to Ubuntu 10.04. My problem is that i've purged a package and can't install this package back. Because I can't see it in the aptitude or apt-get's package list. I think I have play with some configurations. How can i fix this issue?

Edit: The problematic packages are sun-java6* . I installed sun-java6-jdk from oracle's web page and installed other ones using APT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, tell us the package name. Second, in my opinion you have installed the package by using dpkg or a third source which is not in your APT repository. Anyway, cough up that name. :P

Update: There is a post which says the package is avaliable in the partner repository. You can simply comment it out in /etc/apt/sources.list , removing the "#" before the line (which contains 'partner'). (You can edit it with `sudo nano -w /etc/apt/sources.list` . After that , do an `sudo apt-get update` and install the packages with `sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre` (not sure if thats the correct package name, look it up using Synaptics package manager or aptitude.
Here is a post from a website.
$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner"
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre
 (And yeah this seems to be the solution , its just not documented yet.)

Comment: the problematic packages are sun-java6*, simply all packages starting with sun-java6 :). I've only installed sun-java6-jdk from oracle's web site. Because there was some security issue in the jdk version of ubuntu.(About a week later they put the fixed jdk in the repository). And i was having some problems with java so i decided to purge em all and reinstall with aptitude(thougt that there is an issue with 10.04 and the previously installed packages ). But at the moment all the sun-java6 packages are missing.

Comment: Editing the main post instead...

Comment: Thanx that fixed the problem