# How to setup Java development environment in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: linux, java, ubuntu-10.04

I have just installed Ubuntu 10.04 in my Laptop and I'm a beginner to Linux operating systems. I want to setup a Java development environment in my system. Things I need:

1. Eclipse
2. JDK 1.6
3. Apache Tomcat

Can anyone please guide me how to install these software in my Ubuntu 10.04?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) You should download this from [Eclipse's website](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) (unpack it).
2) Read my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/140223/cant-install-back-a-purged-package-in-ubuntu).
3) Open the Synaptic package manager and type: `tomcat` . Select which one you want, install it.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you start with:

```
sudo aptitude install sun-java6-jdk eclipse-rcp libtomcat6-java
```